# How to target update 1 / update 2, etc .. in instruction {$IF CompilerVersion > xx}

Tags: delphi

I often do stuff like this :

```
  {$IF CompilerVersion > 31} // berlin
    {$MESSAGE WARN 'check the code below'}
  {$ENDIF}
```

but how to also target berlin update 1, berlin update 2, etc ... ?
because 31 is for berlin and 32 is for tokyo ... no gap between.

Comment: AFAIK, `CompilerVersion` is a floating point type, so there *could* be values like `31.1` and `31.2`. But I can't check this right now (no Delphi Berlin here, at the moment). Should be easy to check for you, though. It should be in System.pas.

Comment: in system.pas they just write this: 
(*
const
  CompilerVersion = 0.0;

  CompilerVersion is assigned a value by the compiler when
  the system unit is compiled.  It indicates the revision level of the
  compiler features / language syntax, which may advance independently of
  the RTLVersion.  CompilerVersion can be tested in $IF expressions and
  should be used instead of testing for the VERxxx conditional define.
  Always test for greater than or less than a known revision level.
  It's a bad idea to test for a specific revision level.
*)

Comment: Then simply write it out to screen, e.g. using something like `Writeln(CompilerVersion:5:2);` in a simple console program.

Comment: CompilerVersion doesn't change between Berlin, Upd1 and Upd2. Can you elaborate why you need to distinguish between these sub releases? Perhaps CompilerVersion is not suitable for that.

Comment: @UweRaabe simply because as we don't have access anymore to private access via class helper we need to copy/past the EXACT structure of an object to access his member. so if between an update this structure change our code can crash. thanks emb for removing this very usefull feature !

Comment: @Henry, class helpers still can be used for access of private members. Just use `with Self.member` and all is fine.

Comment: @Henry: that is true for all subversions of Berlin (release, update 1, etc.), so knowing the exact subversion is irrelevant. and, as LURD already wrote: you can still access private members. It has just become a little less convenient. Why do you actually need such access? Doing that is a hack, no matter if you do it with class helpers or any other way.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: firemonkey is too much a mess to be used without any hack ;)

Comment: Have a look at the `RTLVersion` constant instead of the `CompilerVersion` constant. `CompilerVersion` is incremented when the compiler is updated, typically only in major releases. `RTLVersion` is incremented when the RTL is updated, such as in update packs.

Comment: @RemyLebeau : deserve to be the answer !

Comment: Correction to my earlier comment about class helpers. Use this pattern to make it work for private/protected members in Berlin,Tokyo: `with Self do begin "member access" end;`

Answer (score 0):

Peek in your registry.

I have Seattle Update 1, my about box mentions *Delphi 10 Seattle and C++Builder 10 Seattle Subscription Update 1* <sup>*</sup>.

That is in `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\17.0\InstalledUpdates` under a value named `Main Product Update`.

You may have to do some detective work to determine the actual strings
(or readers here can supply the value strings they have).

You can't use your conditional compilation, but at least you can warn from code.

---

Notes:
- Looking at the version info of a CodeGear DLL could also be an option.
- That same info is also in `C:\programdata\embarcadero\bds\17.0\installedupdates.dat` and `C:\users\all users\embarcadero\bds\17.0\installedupdates.dat`

<sup>* Note the missing space in C++Builder</sup>

Comment: thank Jan, however i need this in conditional compilation :( it's crazy that emb didn't think about it ...